# Track how long user views a slide of a online image slideshow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, event-tracking, time-tracking

I am currently working on a project that requires the web application to track how long user stays on one slide of a slide show. Say the online slideshow has 5 (slide-1.png to slide-5.png) slides, user can navigate through the slideshow using "Next" and "Previous" button.

User will always start on slide-1.png, after 5 seconds user clicked on "Next" button and goes to slide-2.png. After 10 seconds the user clicked on "Previous" to go back slide-1.png and stayed there for 5 seconds.

This is basically event-based application. The time will start recording when user click on "Next" or "Previous", and stop recording the old session and start recording the new session when user click on "Next" or "Previous" again.

User does not go to a new html page after clicking on "Next"/"Previous". It is simply images changing src information.

Any ideas about how I should approach this? I am currently using PHP, Javascript, and Java in my web application.

Comment: Do you need to account for the case where they view a slide and then walk away from the computer for a day? Or is there a max value where you would consider them "idle"?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to capture the time when they start viewing a slide:

```
var startTime = new Date();
```

Then capture the time when the slide goes away:

```
var endTime = new Date();
```

Then you can calculate the elapsed time.

```
var elapsed = endTime - startTime; // elapsed time in milliseconds
```

If you need to account for the case where a user opens a slide and then walks away from the computer you could also start a timeout timer that will log the user as having timed out for that slide.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  endTime = 'Timed out.';
}, ((3 * 60) * 60) * 1000); // ((3hrs * 60mins) * 60secs) * 1000ms
```

After 3 hours it would set the endTime to `'Timed out.'` and you could use that to know that the user walked away from that particular slide and didn't finish viewing the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript function that loops over and 'sniffs' for the set conditions that you define will work best for this scenario.  The approach you should take is to assign each .png it's own ID attribute.  Create variables via JavaScript and jQuery that specifically targets each image.  Then attach a mousedown or click event to the slideshow that will detect which image is visible and trigger a timer for that specific image.  Ofcourse, you will need input fields hidden on the page for each image for the counter to increment into.

In the link, you will see similar functionality whereby when a use clicks on the 'zoom in' component a timer will start.  It will only stop when the user clicks out of the image.

The JavaScript function is call setInterval() and can be stopped with clearInterval().  For best results, create the setInterval() function as a variable.

Sample variable:

```
var firstSlide = jQuery('img#slide1');
```

**Sample Condition 01**:

```
if (firstSlide.length > 0)
{
    //start counter with setInterval();
}
```

**Sample Condition 02**:

```
if (firstSlide.is(':visible'))
{
    //start counter with setInterval();
}
```

To ensure minimal overlaps in the timer and ensure stricter behavior, I would suggest applying a unique CSS class to the slideshow container when it is visible on click and to remove it when it is not visible.

**Sample Condition 03**:

```
slideShow.click( function() {
slideShow.addClass('isClicked');
});
if (firstSlide.is(':visible') && jQuery('slideShow.isClicked').length > 0)
{
    //start counter with setInterval();
}
```

http://www.alexldixon.com/clicktimerhelp.htm

Another example where the setInvertval can 'sniff' dynamic conditions, is making element heights equal even when the window resizes and text wraps.

https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/ojoevj1k/

```
var makeSameHeight = setInterval( function() {
    var currentTextHeight = $('div.myClass-content').height() + "px";
    var imgDivHeight = $('div.imgUrl').height() + "px";
    if (currentTextHeight === imgDivHeight)
    {
        var doNothing = "";
    } else {
        $('div.imgUrl, div.postImageUrl, a.myClass').css("height", currentTextHeight);
    }
}, 50);
```

Lastly, you can also use the new Date() function.

I hope this helps.